# Making Bootstrap Nav-Pills Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a little trouble making the following nav pills responsive. The first 2 "hidden-phone" classes work fine and as they should but the "visible-phone" class below doesn't appear when I shrink the screen size. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class ="span3">
       <div class="hidden-phone">
          <a><img src=img/logobanner.jpg alt="mobile application development, mobile app        development, mobile application developer, mobile app developer, bespoke mobile application, social media agency london, social media agency manchester"></a>
       </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-phone">
    <div class ="span5 offset7">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
  <li><a href="testimonials.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://resonate.so/blog">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

  <div class ="span3">
    <div class="visible-phone">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">Gallery</a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Layer with class `Visible-phone` is part of precedent layer `hidden-phone`. I think you forgot to close your precedent `div`. Be careful with indentation!

Here is my Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/kydEc/

Use vertical splitter to shrink view.

Comment: Hello Alexandre, works on the JS fiddle but implemented still having issues tried it on a seperate blank page as well still with no luck